# count elements of a class within another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to count elements of a particular class within another element?

I have the class of the parent element, but there are other elements with that class. So if for example I have an element that i get to like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.countButton', function(){

    var parent = $(this).parents('parentDiv');


});
```

How can I put that element into a selector to count it like this:

`$('.parentDiv > .childDivs').length;`

Is there someway to convert an element into a selector, or something that points to that element? If that makes sense..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the parent element as context for the search:

```
$('.childDivs', parent).length
```

Which is the same as:

```
parent.find('.childDivs').length
```

Comment: They're more than the same -- the first is converted into the second. Using find() is more idiomatic and probably faster. children() will be faster yet if you know you are looking for direct descendants.

Answer (score 2):

So after `var parent = $(this).parents('parentDiv');` you have the element you want and you just want its children with a certain class? If so

```
parent.children('.childDivs').length;
```

For direct descendants or:

```
parent.find('.childDivs').length;
```

To find elements with the 'childDivs' class at any depth with `parent`

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps use:

`document.querySelectorAll('.parentDiv > .childDivs').length`?